# Didn't find class "com.example.tutorial_app.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

```
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tutorial_app/com.example.tutorial_app.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.tutorial_app.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.tutorial_app-00_yPYh84Ld0wplZj_0YwA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.tutorial_app-00_yPYh84Ld0wplZj_0YwA==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.tutorial_app-00_yPYh84Ld0wplZj_0YwA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /product/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(30828):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3264)
E/AndroidRuntime(30828):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3489)
E/AndroidRuntime(30828):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
E/AndroidRuntime(30828):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
```

My flutter app is not launching in real device because of this error. how to to resolve this error? This app is working correctly in chrome but not in real device or emulator

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86_64', 'x86'
            }
        }
    }
```